# React "this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called " only in Build

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm working on a react app base con create-react-app, the app works well on dev server but when I run the build something happen and the app not working.

I use a HOC with some function as context, the function declared in the context (HOC) not working because this is not declared.

Everything work fine on dev, if for test before the build I comment

```
 this.getProducts();
```

on componentDidMount the problems move forward on the next function that use this.

Someone can help me? Thanks in advance.

```
const GlobalContext = React.createContext()

class GlobalProvider extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)


    this.loadingToggle = ( status = null, where = '' ) => {
        // enable and disable loading               
    }

    this.loginFunction = (e, utente_id, password) => {
        // rest api login
    }

    this.logoutFunction = () => {
        // logout
    }


    this.getProducts = () => {

        this.forceUpdate(); 

        this.loadingToggle(true, "getProducts");

        // HERE THE PROBLEMS
        var _this = this; 

        axios.post(Config.apiBaseUrl + '/users/products', {
            token: localStorage.getItem('token')
        })
        .then( (response) => {
            if (response.data.success !== true ){
                // user not exist
            }else{
                // populate user data

                // HERE I USE _this
            }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // catch error
        });

    }



    this.cartVariation = (id, qty, minQty = 0) => {
        // cart action
    }


    this.sendOrder = (addressId) => {
        // send order
    }



    this.state = { 
        isAuth: false,
        loginFunction: this.loginFunction,
        logoutFunction: this.logoutFunction,
        cartVariation: this.cartVariation,
        removeCart: this.removeCart,
        cart: null,
        forceUpdate: this.forceUpdate,
        lastUpdate: new Date().getTime(),
        cartCount: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("mf-cart")) !== null ? Object.keys( JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("mf-cart"))).length : 0,
        loadingToggle: this.loadingToggle,
        loading: false,
        store : {
            mf_product_list : [],
            mf_categories : [],
            mf_users : [],
            mf_users_formatted : [],
            mf_backorders : [],
            mf_backorders_list : [],
            mf_address : []
        },
        sendOrder: this.sendOrder
    }


  }

  componentDidMount () {

    if (localStorage.getItem('token') !== null && localStorage.getItem('token-timestamp') !== null ){
        this.setState({isAuth : true});
    }
        this.getProducts();
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <GlobalContext.Provider
        value={{
          isAuth: this.state.isAuth,
          authToken: null,
          loginFunction: this.state.loginFunction,
          logoutFunction: this.state.logoutFunction,
          cartVariation: this.state.cartVariation,
          removeCart: this.state.removeCart,
          cart: null,
          forceUpdate: this.state.forceUpdate,
          lastUpdate: this.state.lastUpdate,          
          cartCount: this.state.cartCount, 
          loading: this.state.loading,
          store: this.state.store,
          sendOrder: this.sendOrder
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </GlobalContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}

const GlobalConsumer = GlobalContext.Consumer

export { GlobalProvider, GlobalConsumer }
```

Comment: You have everything in the constructor function and super has not had a chance to load.

Answer (score 0):

Change the function binding from Class properties

```
this.getProducts = () => {
// ...
}
```

to bind it in the constructor (ES2015)

```
constructor(props) {
  // ...
  this.getProducts = this.getProducts.bind(this);
}
```

More information about function binding is [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html).